# Magento2 - Undefined index

Tags: magento2, error, extensions

I have installed a new extension (Mageplaza Better pop-up) and after that when i´m trying to go to configuration stores page it gives me this error:

> Notice: Undefined index: id in
>   /../../../../magento/module-config/Model/Config/Structure/Element/Iterator.php
>   on line 59

I have already tried to use this solution: [Admin config error: Undefined index: id in Iterator.php on line 59](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/202669/admin-config-error-undefined-index-id-in-iterator-php-on-line-59)

But it didn´t work.

Thank you

Comment: What is your magento2 version?

Comment: sorry I forgot to mention that is 2.1 @SukumarGorai

Comment: Do a full reindex **php bin/magento index:reindex** and try again.

Comment: @YlgenGuxholli the error is still alive, the awkward thing is that the extension is working perfectly

Comment: Did you install it through composer? I have installed it in magento 2.2.4 and it works perfectly without any error.

Comment: Try this commands also: **php bin/magento cache:flush** , **php bin/magento setup:upgrade** , **php bin/magento setup:di:compile**, **php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy**

Comment: @SukumarGorai yes I installed via composer, i will probably reinstall and try again

Comment: @YlgenGuxholli you didn´t wrote any command

Comment: Updated the comment @user6505433

Comment: @YlgenGuxholli still not working, I will try to reinstall

Comment: @YlgenGuxholli its working

Comment: @user6505433 glad it`s solved.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution and it´s very simple.

Just try to reinstall the module `Mageplaza_Core` and `Mageplaza_BetterPopup`

Then flush your cache and do a system upgrade.

And should work with no errors.

Thank you all for your time !

Answer (score 0):

If you want to uninstall the module need to follow the proper steps of M2

Please check magento DB if unnecessary tables there mean , delete it.