# M2: Exception #0 (Exception): Notice: Undefined index: id in

Tags: magento2, exception, undefined

**I upgraded Magento from 2.3.4 to 2.4**

After upgrade,it's impossible to open `stores ---> configuration` I got Exception:

```
1 exception(s):
Exception #0 (Exception): Notice: Undefined index: id in /home/shop/domains/domain.pl/public_html/vendor/magento/module-config/Model/Config/Structure/Element/Iterator.php on line 63

Exception #0 (Exception): Notice: Undefined index: id in /home/shop/domains/domain.pl/public_html/vendor/magento/module-config/Model/Config/Structure/Element/Iterator.php on line 63
<pre>#1 Magento\Config\Model\Config\Structure\Element\Iterator->setElements(array('magentech' => array('id' => 'magentech', 'translate' => 'label', 'sortOrder' => 1, 'label' => 'Magentech.com', '_elementType' => 'tab', 'children' => array('market' => array('id' => 'market', 'translate' => 'label', 'type' => 'text', 'sortOrder' => 1, 'showInDefault' => 1, 'showInWebsite' => 1, 'showInStore' => 1, 'class' => 'separator-top', 'label' => 'SM Market', 'tab' => 'magentech', 'resource' => 'Sm_Market::confi...', 'children' => array('general' => array('id' => 'general', 'translate' => 'label', 'type' => 'text', 'sortOrder' => 1, 'showInDefault' => 1, 'showInWebsite' => 1, 'showInStore' => 1, 'label' => 'General Options', 'children' => array('theme_color' => array('id' => 'theme_color', 'translate' => 'label', 'type' => 'text', 'sortOrder' => 5, 'showInDefault' => 1, 'showInWebsite' => 1, 'showInStore' => 1, 'label' => 'Theme Color', 'frontend_model' => 'Sm\Market\Block\...', '_elementType' => 'field', 'path' => 'market/general'), 'heading_bodyfont' => array('id' => 'heading_bodyfont', 'translate' => 'label', 'type' => 'text', 'sortOrder' => 10, 'showInDefault' => 1, 'showInWebsite' => 1, 'showInStore' => 1, 'label' => 'Body Font', 'frontend_model' => 'Magento\Config\B...', '_elementType' => 'field', 'path' => 'market/general'), 'body_font' => array('id' => 'body_font', 'translate' => 'label', 'type' => 'select', 'sortOrder' => 15, 'showInDefault' => 1, 'showInWebsite' => 1, 'showInStore' => 1, 'label' => 'Main Font', 'source_model' => 'Sm\Market\Model\...', '_elementType' => 'field', 'path' => 'market/general'), 'body_google_font' => array('id' => 'body_google_font', 'translate' => 'label', 'type' => 'select', 'sortOrder' => 20, 'showInDefault' => 1, 'showInWebsite' => 1, 'showInStore' => 1, 'label' => 'Google Font Name', 'source_model' => 'Sm\Market\Model\...', 'depends' => array('fields' => array('body_font' => array('id' => 'market/general/b...', 'value' => 'google_font', '_elementType' => 'field', 'dependPath' => array('market', 'general', 'body_font')))), '_elementType' => 'field', 'path' => 'market/general'), 'font_size' => array('id' => 'font_size', 'translate' => 'label', 'type' => 'select', 'sortOrder' => 25, 'showInDefault' => 1, 'showInWebsite' => 1, 'showInStore' => 1, 'label' => 'Font Size', 'source_model' => 'Sm\Market\Model\...', '_elementType' => 'field', 'path' => 'market/general'), 'body_link_color' => array('id' =>
```

`Iterator.php` on line 63

```
/**
 * Set element data
 *
 * @param array $elements
 * @param string $scope
 * @return void
 */
public function setElements(array $elements, $scope)
{
    $this->_elements = $elements;
    $this->_scope = $scope;
    if (count($elements)) {
        $lastElement = end($elements);
        $this->_lastId = $lastElement['id'];
    }
}
```

Comment: check your php version

Comment: I change to 7.3 from 7.4 but still the same issue. Should I upgrade again with 7.3 ?

Comment: after change make sure you restart php

Comment: Unfortunately, this did not solve the problem. PHP restarted. I gave s: up and s: d: c again still the same issue.

Comment: It looks like you use sm market theme that is causing this issue. First I would check updates and doc of this theme.

Comment: If somehow you cannot update theme. You can check this topic, specially part about debugging  Iterator.php https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/202669/admin-config-error-undefined-index-id-in-iterator-php-on-line-59/213076

Comment: This issue meaning one of item config in some module that you working with missing attribute id required. If you don't know which modules try look at all custom 3rd-party modules